# But just so I know, is either way hard? (translate)

Tags: translation

I can't understand this phrase.

I have two way:

1. He/she want to understand it is hard to do or not
2. He/she know what it is way is simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain your examples are grammatically accurate. However, I think the first sentence should be restructured as:

> He/ She wants to understand whether or not it is hard to do.

or

> He/ She wants to understand whether it is hard to do, or not.

**Meaning**:

> The subject (he/ she) wants to know whether the task/ job/ action is easily doable or if it is very difficult to complete/ perform.

and as for the second sentence, I'm not sure what you meant with it. If you could clarify that sentence, I will edit the answer to try and restructure the sentence and tell you what it means.